# iCloud App not installing

Tags: icloud, windows

iCloud not installing.

I installed iCloud Setup 3 times and when l installed it...

> "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support panel or package vendor." iCloud.

[image: "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support panel or package vendor." iCloud.]

Comment: First step, re-download the installer *using a different browser*.

Comment: 2nd step, delete all temporary files (Windows and User folder) and reboot